# Deleting what wasn't allocated with new using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, struct

**Update: Please Note, I am forced to return a pointer to the result since I need to support multiple operations in one line (will be used in python)**

Today, I have faced the *hardest* problem in my programming career Ever, So I hope someone can help.

In `graph_p.h` I have:

```
typedef struct Graph* Graph_P;
```

**(Graph_P is a pointer for a Graph)**

While `Graph` Is another class which I defined

In `graph_p.cpp` I have the following functions:

```
Graph_P create()
{
    try {
        Graph_P graph=new Graph;
        return graph;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &) {
        std::cout << "Error: Allocation Failed" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
}

void destroy(Graph_P graph_p)
{
    delete graph_p;
}
```

And the following `graphUnion` function **(which is our topic**):

```
Graph_P graphUnion(Graph_P graph_in1, Graph_P graph_in2, Graph_P graph_out) {
    try {
        *graph_out=(*graph_in1)+(*graph_in2);
//I have defined operator + between two graphs which returns a new graph built using default c'tor **not using new**

        destroy(graph_out);
        return graph_out;
    }
    catch (CException::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

**What's the problem?**

In case `operator +` failed I'm deleting the content of `graph_out` which shouldn't be done.

**Suggested Solution:**

Saving `graph_out` content in a temporary `Graph_P` object like this:

```
Graph_P graphUnion(Graph_P graph_in1, Graph_P graph_in2, Graph_P graph_out) {
    try {
        Graph tmp=*graph_out;
        tmp=(*graph_in1)+(*graph_in2);
        destroy(graph_out);
        graph_out=&tmp;
        return graph_out;
    }
    catch (CException::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

**What's the problem?**

I am putting a value inside graph_out that wasn't allocated via `new` so if the user types `destroy(graph_out)` outside the function, that would be an undefined action since I read:

**You need to `delete` only what you `new`ed**

How may I fix this?

Comment: Don't use pointers seem like the obvious advice. Often given, often ignored. What is your reason for using pointers? There's nothing on the code above that requires pointer use.

Comment: Your latest version of `graphUnion` cannot possibly work because it returns a pointer to a local object. that object `tmp` is destroyed when the function is exited, and so you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: Modern C++ almost never uses `new` or `delete`, but rather uses the C++ library's rich collection of containers, which automatically take care of `delete`ing only what's `new`ed. Smart pointers are used in highly complicated situations, which do the same. You should simply rewrite your code using containers and/or smart pointers. Problem solved!

Comment: Finally your actual problem appears not to exist `In case operator + failed I'm deleting the content of graph_out`. If operator+ is throwing an exception on an error (you don't say this but I'm assuming it's true) then there's nothing in that code which will delete the contents of `graph_out`.

Comment: @John I am forced to use pointers, that is not a decision I can make

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will connect this code with python using swig and I don't want variable to be deleted whenever non points at it

Comment: Perhaps, and just a suggestion, you hold of on attempting to properly integrate C++ and another language together, until such time you have more experience and better understanding of how C++ works? C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Just learning C++ itself until such point where one begins to understand all its core fundamental principles takes, on average, 3-5 years. Trying to make it work together with another language, but without fully understanding core C++ concepts, will be fraught with pitfalls, unexplained crashes, etc...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik may you kindly suggest what changes should I make in general considering that I MUST return pointers?

Comment: @daniel Is it true that when you say 'in case operator+ fails' what you mean is that operator+ throws an exception? Because if that is the case then I don't see that you original code has any problem at all. What are you seeing that makes you think there is a problem? Your attempted improvment is clearly bugged however.

Comment: @John I don't want to destroy content before I verify I can replace it

Comment: @daniel OK finally I've got it. Why are you passing `group_out` into the function when it's just going to get overwritten. Why not allocate it (and return it) in the function?

Comment: Well, you cannot return a pointer to a local variable, and then attempt to dereference that pointer later. C++ does not work this way. So, whatever you need to do, you must change it, while still following the rule that you can only `delete` what you `new`ed. These are fundamental rules of C++ to which there are no exceptions, and you need to figure out how to do what you need to do, while remaining compliant with these rules.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> typedef struct Graph* Graph_P;
> ```

This is a bad idea. Obfuscating pointer like this should be avoided.

---

Problem is here:

```
Graph tmp=*graph_out;
// ...
graph_out=&tmp;
return graph_out;
```

You create a graph that local to the function. It is automatically destroyed when the function returns. You return a pointer to that graph. The returned pointer will be invalid outside of the function. Attempting to delete or access the non-existing value through that dangling pointer results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: @daniel Don't return pointers to local variables. Use smart pointers. In case of graph union, return a graph rather than a pointer.

Comment: I'm not returning pointer to local variable but to a variable given from the user's input, Plus I am FORCED to return a pointer of any kind to the result (Yes even though if I saved it)

Comment: @daniel `tmp` is a local variable. `graph_out` points to `tmp`. You return `graph_out`. Therefore you return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @daniel You are returning a pointer to a local variable

Comment: @John in the edited function, look at the first version before I missed things up

Answer (score -3):

I think the simplest solution would be to add if statement in *destroy()* function to make sure that graph_p isn't a nullptr:

```
void destroy(Graph_P graph_p)
{
    if (graph_p != nullptr) {
        delete graph_p;
    }
}
```

I think it would be a good idea to make Graph_P a smart pointer (if you're using at least C++11) - memory allocation would be easier.

Comment: `delete graph_p;` when graph_p is nullptr is well-defined in C++.

Comment: No, this doesn't cut it.

Comment: Last paragraph is good suggestion. First one is not a solution.